# "ELF: not found" and "syntax error: unexepected \"(\"" in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to build a Docker image for [`beanstalkd-cli`](https://github.com/schickling/beanstalkd-cli). The image builds successfully, but when I run `docker run -it myimage`, it fails with:

```
/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: line 1: ELF: not found
/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: line 2: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Does this mean the build is bad? Or do I need to tweak `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD`?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

LABEL maintainer="Coby Tamayo <ctamayo@sitecrafting.com"

# Install openssl, beanstalkd-cli
RUN apk add --update openssl && \
  wget https://github.com/schickling/beanstalkd-cli/releases/download/0.3.0/beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz && \
  chmod +x beanstalkd-cli && \
  mv beanstalkd-cli /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli && \
  rm beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli"]
```

#### Update 1

When I remove the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` completely, running the container drops me into a shell, where I can verify that beanstalkd-cli has execute permissions set:

```
$ docker run -it myimage
/ # which beanstalkd-cli
/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
/ # ls -la /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
-rwxrwxr-x    1 1000     1000       3020529 Feb 23  2015 /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
```

Just "for fun," I also tried setting only `ENTRYPOINT`, with no command, since I really don't care about running anything except `beanstalkd-cli` commands in this container:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli"]
# no more CMD
```

When I `docker run` *this*, I get:

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Same result if I add the original `CMD` back in. Huh?

#### Update 2

```
# file /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=63a19b18574643c1da5bafd5bd56fc26af22ab05, not stripped

# uname -a
Linux 6882ec36481d 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 Linux

# /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: not found
```

Comment: Check that `beanstalk-cli` has execute permissions. It looks like the shell is trying to run it as a shell script.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks! Isn't that what `chmod +x beanstalkd-cli` does? See edit.

Comment: Can you run `/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli` interactively inside your container?

Comment: @thatotherguy interesting, see update #2, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it has an unmet library dependency. If you have `ldd`, run `ldd /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli`

Comment: ...since you're starting from Alpine, which is *extremely* minimal, such unmet dependencies is not remotely surprising. I'll hazard these binaries are probably linked against glibc, which Alpine doesn't provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Diagnosing The Problem

Using your Dockerfile:

```
docker run 04d32bac400e '-xlic' 'ldd /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli'
```

...emits:

```
+ ldd /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9044206000)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: __gcc_personality_v0: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: __rawmemchr: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_DeleteException: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_RaiseException: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_FindEnclosingFunction: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_GetIP: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_Backtrace: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli: _Unwind_Resume: symbol not found
```

So -- the `beanstalkd` libraries you're using are linked against `libgcc_s.so.1` and `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, neither of which is provided by the Alpine 3.5 base image; hence, "no such file or directory" when trying to run the executable.

---

#### The Easy Solution

Consider a heavier-weight base image; the following, for example, works properly:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

LABEL maintainer="Coby Tamayo <ctamayo@sitecrafting.com>"

# Install openssl, beanstalkd-cli
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/schickling/beanstalkd-cli/releases/download/0.3.0/beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz && \
  chmod +x beanstalkd-cli && \
  mv beanstalkd-cli /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli && \
  rm beanstalkd-cli-linux.tar.gz

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd-cli"]
```

Comment: Works indeed! Just out of curiosity, what exactly is the `'-xlic'` doing? I haven't seen that syntax in a `docker run` before.

Comment: It's syntax for `sh`, since you had that set as the `ENTRYPOINT`. The `-x` tells it to log each command it runs (which, by the way, lets us figure out where the `unexpected "("` comes from); the `-l` and `-i` set login and interactive flags; the `-c` says that the next argument is a shell script to run.

Comment: aha, makes sense. Thanks so much.